# Access PyQt5 Objects from outside the MainWin Class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am developing an application that reads MS Access DBs to produce extracts and data manipulation into SharePoint.  One of my challenges is that I will need to write a lengthy GUI interface with many simple events.  To keep the code organized I will be writing subroutines and import into the main program. As a result there will be code that needs to run outside the class and access objects inside the class.  I am having a problem determining the proper syntax.

Or is there a way to import directly into the class to avoid the redefining issue?

In the InitUI there is a call to subroutine called TestIt()  in that sub routine I print a message to verify the code is getting called.  Then I try to set the text value of a Single Line Edit object from the main window.  The question what is the proper way to call it?  Do I need to redefine the variable.

The main program is this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Main import Ui_MainWin
import sys, time, os, configparser
import pyodbc
from ServerQueue import *

class MainWindow_EXEC():
    def __init__(self):             # This section has to be laid out this way 
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        win = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWin()
        self.ui.setupUi(win) 
        self.initUI()               # Inits that need to happen before start up

        win.setWindowTitle("This is the Title!")
        #win.resize(800,600)
        win.show()  
        sys.exit(app.exec_()) 

    def initUI(self):
        TestIt()
        self.ui.cmbAppCodes.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)
        try:
            self.conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver
            (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ='+ dbPath + ';',autocommit=True)
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        except:
            print("Error opening the database!")
            qApp.quit()
        print(dbPath)
        self.loadAppCodes()

    def loadAppCodes(self):
        self.ui.cmbAppCodes.clear()
        sql = "SELECT [App Code], [App Name] from [App List] ORDER BY [App Code];"
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        res = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for code in res:
            self.ui.cmbAppCodes.addItem("{} - {}".format(code[0], code[1]))

    def selectionchange(self,i):
        App = self.ui.cmbAppCodes.itemText(i)
        sql = "SELECT * FROM [LCM Application List] WHERE [App Code] = '" + App[0:3] + "';"
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        res = self.cursor.fetchone()

        self.ui.lneAPM.setText(res[3])
        self.ui.lneTPM.setText(res[21])
        self.ui.lneAPO.setText(res[4])

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Load up the init file
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
def iniSettings():
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        os.system('cls')
        Home = os.path.expanduser('~') + "\\"
        D = "W"
    else:
        os.system('clear')
        Home = os.path.expanduser('~') + "/"
        D = "O"

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(Home + 'LCM.ini')           # Path to LCM.ini file

    Configs = config['DEFAULT']             # Read the DEFAULT section
    return [Home, Configs['LCMDB'], Configs['CR1'], D]


##########################################################################################
# Main Body
###########################################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Paths = iniSettings() # This is to pull the ini data for paths and what not.
    hmPath = Paths[0]
    dbPath = Paths[1]
    cr1Path = Paths[2]
    myOS = Paths[3] 

    print("Home:     {}\nCR1:      {}\nDatabase: {}\n".format(hmPath, cr1Path, dbPath))

    MainWindow_EXEC() # Becuase the init is laid out this way this is all that is needed
    print("Application completed")enter code here



#This file is imported and is called ServerQueue.py
def TestIt():
    print("TestIt")
    self.ui.lneAPM.setText("Testing")

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Processing Loop
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("\n ********* \n This file is not meant to be run directly! \n ********* \n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything backwards. You are trying to get the elements of business logic to consume the GUI, but the correct logic is the reverse: The GUI consumes the information from the elements of business logic. Considering the above, the Test () function should not modify the GUI directly, but provide the information to the GUI, one way to implement that is to return the text.

```py
def TestIt():
    print("TestIt")
    return "Testing"
```

```
# ...

def initUI(self):
    self.ui.lneAPM.setText(TestIt())
    # ...
```

<sub>If the above does not solve the problem then you probably have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so I recommend you to rewrite your question better providing a better [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)</sub>

Comment: Thank for the answer sometimes the simple ones are the hardest to see.  Your answer makes perfect sense I should have known that.  However that gives rise to another question.  There are lots of events that will occur in this application.  While the coade will not be complicated

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sometimes the simple ones are the hardest to see.  Your answer makes perfect sense I should have known that.  

However that gives rise to another question.  There are lots of events that will occur in this application.  While the code will not be complicated it will be lengthy and some functions will need to return multiple values.  I know that's a lengthy answer and I am not looking to be educated on coding styles on stackoverflow.  Any quick/simple suggestions or reading would be greatly appreciated.

Again thank you for the answer to my original question.